# Relationship between CLT for estimator of sample and number of combinations for subsample?

Tags: estimation, sampling, python, central-limit-theorem, combinatorics

What is the relationship between the Central Limit Theorem as applied to the expected value of an estimator of a parent sample and the number of possible combinations of a subsample used to calculate that estimator?

I've made a reproducible experiment to illustrate (Python 3x, IPython 4x, Jupyter Notebook 4x):
[20160115T103000Z_StackExchange_CrossValidated_CLT-vs-ncombos.ipynb](https://gist.github.com/stharrold/c829d721470c363f27bf)

```
# Requires Python 3x.
# Import standard packages.
import os
import subprocess
# Import installed packages.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# Generate samples.
np.random.seed(seed=3)
size_parent = 29
sample_parent = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=size_parent)
sizes_stds = list()
sizes_means = list()
sizes_ncomboswrepl = list()
sizes_ncombosworepl = list()
percentiles = [16, 50, 84]
num_subsamples = 1000
for size_sub in range(1, size_parent+1):
    means = list()
    stds = list()
    for _ in range(num_subsamples):
        sample_sub = np.random.choice(sample_parent, size=size_sub, replace=True)
        means.append(np.mean(sample_sub))
        stds.append(np.std(sample_sub))
    sizes_means.append((size_sub, *np.percentile(means, q=percentiles)))
    sizes_stds.append((size_sub, *np.percentile(stds, q=percentiles)))
    sizes_ncomboswrepl.append((size_sub, scipy.misc.comb(size_parent, size_sub, repetition=True)))
    sizes_ncombosworepl.append((size_sub, scipy.misc.comb(size_parent, size_sub, repetition=False)))
sizes_means = np.asarray(sizes_means)
sizes_stds = np.asarray(sizes_stds)
sizes_ncomboswrepl = np.asarray(sizes_ncomboswrepl)
sizes_ncombosworepl = np.asarray(sizes_ncombosworepl)

# Make plot.
sns.set()
print("Size of parent sample =", size_parent)
print("Num. subsamples used for estimate =", num_subsamples)
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax0.set_title(
    "Est. mean, stddev. of parent sample; num. possible\n" +
    "combos of subsample vs subsample size")
ax0.plot(
    sizes_means[:, 0], sizes_means[:, 2],
    marker='.', color=sns.color_palette()[0], label='est mean (dark=actual, shade=16-84th pctls)')
ax0.fill_between(
    sizes_means[:, 0], y1=sizes_means[:, 1], y2=sizes_means[:, 3],
    alpha=0.5, color=sns.color_palette()[0])
ax0.axhline(y=np.mean(sample_parent), color=sns.color_palette(palette='dark')[0])
ax0.plot(
    sizes_stds[:, 0], sizes_stds[:, 2],
    marker='.', color=sns.color_palette()[1], label='est stddev (dark=actual, shade=16-84th pctls)')
ax0.fill_between(
    sizes_stds[:, 0], y1=sizes_stds[:, 1], y2=sizes_stds[:, 3],
    alpha=0.5, color=sns.color_palette()[1])
ax0.axhline(y=np.std(sample_parent), color=sns.color_palette(palette='dark')[1])
ax0.set_xlabel("Size of subsample")
ax0.set_ylabel(
    "Est. mean, stddev. of parent sample")
ylim0 = (-1.0, 1.5)
ax0.set_ylim(ylim0)
nticks = 6
ax0.set_yticks(np.linspace(start=ylim0[0], stop=ylim0[1], num=nticks, endpoint=True))
ax0.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax1.plot(
    sizes_ncomboswrepl[:, 0], np.log10(sizes_ncomboswrepl[:, 1]),
    marker='.', color=sns.color_palette()[2], label='log10 num combos w repl')
ax1.plot(
    sizes_ncombosworepl[:, 0], np.log10(sizes_ncombosworepl[:, 1]),
    marker='.', color=sns.color_palette()[3], label='log10 num combos w/o repl')
ax1.set_ylabel("Log10 number of possible combinations")
ylim1 = (0, 20)
ax1.set_ylim(ylim1)
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(start=ylim1[0], stop=ylim1[1], num=nticks, endpoint=True))
ax1.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(r'~'), 'estimate_vs_subsample_size.jpg'))
plt.show()
```

Scenario (variable names from the notebook above):
If you draw a fixed number of subsamples (`num_subsamples`) from a parent sample *with* replacement, the variance of an estimator calculated from those subsamples does not seem decrease for subsample sizes (`size_sub`) ⪆ half the parent sample size (`size_parent/2`). The number of possible combinations of subsamples (`ncombos`) peaks at `size_sub = size_parent/2`, but only for sampling *without* replacement. Is there a relationship between the variance of an estimator from the subsamples and `ncombos`?

Plot from the notebook above:
For "Size of subsample" (`num_subsamples`) ⪆ 14, there isn't any significant improvement in the variance of the estimators (the estimators are the estimated mean and standard deviation of the parent sample). `size_parent` = 29; the subsamples are drawn *with* replacement; for every subsample size, I draw a subsample 1000 times; and, if the subsamples were drawn *without* replacement, the number of possible subsample combinations would peak at `int(size_parent/2)` = 14, where `ncombos` would = (`size_parent` choose `num_subsamples`) (again, the subsamples were actually drawn *with* replacement).
[image: estimate_vs_subsample_size.jpg]

My guess is that Bayes' Theorem might give a clue ($\mathrm{Est}$ is the value of the estimator, e.g. the mean or standard deviation from the plot; $\mathrm{Data}$ is the drawn subsample):
$P(\mathrm{Est}|\mathrm{Data}) = P(\mathrm{Data}|\mathrm{Est}) \times P(\mathrm{Est})/P(\mathrm{Data})$
$1/P(\mathrm{Data})$ is maximized at `size_sub = int(size_parent/2)` but only for sampling *without* replacement.
$P(\mathrm{Data}|\mathrm{Est})$ is maximized at `size_sub = size_parent`.
$P(\mathrm{Est})$ is constant.
So maybe $P(\mathrm{Data}|\mathrm{Est})/P(\mathrm{Data})$ is constant for `size_sub >= int(size_parent/2)`? But again the experiment is sampling *with* replacement.

To recap my question: What is the formal relationship between the CLT applied to the estimator and the number of combinations for the subsample drawn *with* replacement (and possibly also the connection to Bayes' Theorem if my hunch was on track)?